# Trying to find a CSV file of the UK's coastline coordinates

Tags: python, csv, gis

I've been trying to find a CSV file to be used with a python script, that contains detailed coordinates of the UK's coastline. I've looked on the OS website and found shapefiles, and I've tried to get coordinates out of them by using QGIS but I cant seem to make it work, it crashes almost every time I try something (I'm thinking this might be due to the size of the files)

The script takes a ID letter and a set of coordinates (Lets call this set A) out of one CSV file, and finds the distance from A to all the coordinates in another CSV file, then writes the smallest distance along with the appropriate ID letter to a third CSV file and repeats this process for every ID letter and set of coordinates in the first file. Currently I've made up some coordinates, but i need a file with the real UK coastal coordinates.

Whatever solutions you know of, I need them to be open source or free please.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry SO is only for questions concerning programming. I suggest you close this question and try to find data here: https://www.kaggle.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked with data from [GADM](https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html) which is free (look for *United Kingdom* and file type *SHP*). After download just extract the archive and run the following script:

```
import fiona
adm = fiona.open("gadm36_GBR_0.shp")
#should be a single feature - the whole country
for feature in adm:
    geom = feature["geometry"] 
    #geom["type"] should be MultiPolygon
    for polygon in geom["coordinates"]:
        for ring in polygon:
            for coordinate in ring:
                print(coordinate[0], coordinate[1])
```

You just need to have [fiona](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) installed; please note the script will simply print all coordinates (which at the time of writing are around 416K); if you want to store them as a CSV file use the builtin [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html).

Note that the coastline is a **MultiPolygon** which is a collection of **polygons** (which themselves are a collection of **rings** and the rings have **coordinates**). You can learn more about these types on fiona's manual page.